# I cannot Get JSON data

Tags: json, get, forex

I am trying to include JSON data but my span is empty. Do you have any idea where am I wrong? Just to mentioned I have access key and I am including it in url when I call JSON.

JSON

```
{
"status": true,
"msg": "successfully",
"response": [
{
"id": "1",
"price": "1.1111",
"change": "+0.0008",
"chg_per": "+0.07%",
"last_changed": "2020-01-09 14:12:02",
"symbol": "EUR/USD"
}
],
"info": {
"server_time": "2020-01-09 14:12:06 UTC"
}
}
```

JS

```
<script>
        const api_url = "https://fcsapi.com/api/forex/latest?id=1"
        async function getFX() {
            const response = await fetch(api_url);
            const data = await response.json();
            const { price } = data;

            document.getElementById('bid').textContent = price;
        }
        getFX();

        setInterval(getFX, 3000);
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<span class="py-1 px-2 w-full block rounded bg-dark-800 flex justify-end items-center" id="bid">
                                            <img class=" ml-1 mt-0" src="images/svg/arrowDown.svg" style="width: 9px;height: 10px;">

                                        </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do `document.getElementById('bid').textContent = JSON.stringify(price)`. As you first have to convert that object into string.

Or you could also try first check if `price` have something and then try
`document.getElementById('bid').innerText = JSON.stringify(price)`